# Checking for new messages

Tags: python, telethon

I'm trying to make a simple autoreply script. I've made an infinite loop that request `client.get_message_history(entity, limit=10)` every second. (hopefully there will be no more than 10 new messages this second) Then check if there any new messages and send my reply with `client.send_message`

But i don't think it is very good idea to spam telegram servers each second. May be there are more efficient ways without unnecessary spamming?

Answer (score 0):

you should work with updates. every time a change happens an instance of updates gets to the callback you register for receiving updates.
this might help you [here](http://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/working-with-updates.html)